# Mongoose Validation Error when trying POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a media app that has categories as well as jokes inside it.

When I make a POST request to /api/category/new, I get this error:

```
{
      message: 'Path `joke` is required.',
      name: 'ValidatorError',
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'joke',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    },
```

I also get the same error(below this error) but instead of the `joke` path, for the `user` path.

**Model**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Joke Schema
const jokeSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: String , required: true},
  joke: { type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100 },
});

// Category Schema
const categorySchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  description: { type: String, required: false },
  likes: { type: Number },
  jokes: [jokeSchema],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("category", categorySchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model("joke", jokeSchema);
```

**Route**

```js
const router = require("express").Router();

//category model
const Category = require("../models/model");

// POST /api/category/new : Creates a new cartgory
router.post("/new", (req, res) => {
  const newCategory = new Category({
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description,
    likes: 0,
    jokes: [],
  });
  newCategory
    .save()
    .then((category) => res.json(category))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your `module.exports`. You have two of them in `models/model.js`:

```js
module.exports = mongoose.model("category", categorySchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model("joke", jokeSchema);
```

Hence when you `const Category = require('../models/model')` you are getting the jokeSchema instead of the category, hence the validations error related to the jokes schema.

Just remove `module.exports = mongoose.model("joke", jokeSchema);` and it should work, or do them as follows:

**models/models.js**

```js
module.exports = {};
module.exports.category = mongoose.model('category', categorySchema);
module.exports.joke = mongoose.model('joke', jokeSchema);
```

**routes/CategoryRouter.js**

```
//category model
const Category = require('../models/model').category;
```